# why am i not able to set local variables properly in ASM? (using emu8086)

Tags: assembly, tasm, emu8086

new to asm so this might be obvious, however -
this is the relevant part of the code:

```
localX equ [bp-4]
    localY equ [bp-6]
    localZ equ [bp-8]
    mov ax, [bp+4]
    mov localX, ax
    mov ax, [bp+6]
    mov localY, ax
    mov ax, [bp+8]
    mov localZ, ax
```

when i compile it and run it, the emulator seems to interpret the localX/Y/Z variables as [bp] +00h, instead of [bp] -04h for example. i tried to replace the local variables with the actual values (so instead of mov localX its mov [bp-4]) and it worked correctly, but i still have no idea what im doing wrong..
for context, this is the entire code:

```
org 100h

.data 

.code

.start
    mov ax, @data
    mov ds, ax
    xor ax, ax
    push 6 
    push 8
    push 3
    call xyz
    
xyz proc
    push bp
    mov bp, sp
    push ax
    sub sp, 6
    localX equ [bp-4]
    localY equ [bp-6]
    localZ equ [bp-8]
    mov ax, [bp+4]
    mov localX, ax
    mov ax, [bp+6]
    mov localY, ax
    mov ax, [bp+8]
    mov localZ, ax
    add sp, 6
    pop ax
    pop bp
    ret 6
endp xyz
    jmp exitL
exitL:    
.exit
```

thanks :)

Comment: It appears what you really want is a macro. I've never used emu8086 but `equ` may only be for *constants* (probably numerical), not for macro expansion. I may be wrong. Inspecting the generated machine code would definitively tell. I wouldn't use emu8086 for writing assembly code that's too structured, it's better to use a proper assembler for that.

Comment: I stand corrected: it appears it's a bug in older versions of flat assembler (the assembler behind emu8086). The latest version generates the correct code. You can try downloading fasm separately and replacing the one emu8086 ships with.

Comment: @MargaretBloom thanks sm! :)
got any idea how to check where the files emu8086 uses for fasm should be? tried poking around in the install folder and the config but found nothing

Comment: In masm `equ` can be used in this way `localX equ <[bp-4]>`. Everything in `< ... >` is string. If You use code for example `mov ax, localX`, compiler will see `mov ax, [bp-4]`. But emu8086 uses fasm I think.

Comment: @MargaretBloom: EMU8086 syntax is more like MASM than FASM.  In FASM, `mov di, symbol` is a mov-immediate (like NASM), but in EMU8086 it's a load.  And FASM's `equ` is always a text substitution, I think. 
 https://github.com/AhmadNaserTurnkeySolutions/emu8086/blob/b99ea60f5dbf8647f278eef60ed1bd8a174468e5/examples/fasm_compatibility.asm#L24 has comments comparing FASM vs. EMU8086 syntax.  Google found some FASM forum posts from people saying they're using FASM with EMU8086, like maybe creating an executable with FASM and running it inside EMU8086 to use its simulator + debugger?

Answer (score -1):

[image]

If You use normal coding instead of `localX`,`localY` and `localZ` everything works fine.

```
    mov ax, [bp+4]      ; ax = 3
    mov [bp-4], ax      ; bp = fff4 - 4 = fff0, [fff0] = 3
    mov ax, [bp+6]      ; ax = 8 
    mov [bp-6], ax      ; bp = fff4 - 6 = ffee, [ffee] = 8
    mov ax, [bp+8]      ; ax = 6 
    mov [bp-8], ax      ; bp = fff4 - 8 = ffec, [fff0] = 6
```

When You define symbolic constants as below, without square brackets:

```
    localX equ bp-4
    localY equ bp-6
    localZ equ bp-8
```

Emu8086 generates this code in place of labels:

```
    localX = [bp]-04h
    localY = [bp]-06h
    localZ = [bp]-08h
```

Result will be the same as first example.

When You define symbolic constants as

```
    localX equ [bp-4]
    localY equ [bp-6]
    localZ equ [bp-8]
```

Emu8086 calculates what this means. `bp = fff4` and if You `sub 4`, `sub 6` and `sub 8` under those addresses are `0's` so result will be the same under every label `[bp] + 00h`

```
    localX equ    [fff4 - 4 = fff0]  ; [fff0] = 0
    localY equ    [fff4 - 6 = ffee]  ; [ffee] = 0
    localZ equ    [fff4 - 8 = ffec]  ; [ffec] = 0
```

Comment: This question is tagged [emu8086] and [tasm], which are two different assemblers which use very similar syntax.  You're talking about a third assembler, FASM, which uses significantly different syntax (e.g. `mov edi, symbol` is a mov-immediate in FASM, unlike MASM-style assembler like EMU8086).  FASM's `equ` is also different from many other assemblers, being a text substitution I think, so it's unlikely that TASM or EMU8086 behave the same as FASM for this either.

Comment: Maybe author used wrong tag (tasm). In EMU8086 folder I have FASM and what I posted above is straight from EMU8086 emulator window.

Comment: This answer is wrong for FASM.  I just tried it with `localX equ [bp-4]` / `mov localX, ax` in a file, `fasm foo.asm` to make a flat binary.  `ndisasm -b16 foo.bin` shows it assembled to `8946FC            mov [bp-0x4],ax` as expected.  Your explanation makes no sense; you seem to be saying FASM know at assemble-time that the *contents of memory* at those locations below BP would be zero, and define the EQU as an integer `0` (so `mov 0, ax`?  that doesn't assemble), or as `[bp+0]`.

Comment: But memory contents are a run-time thing so that's impossible.  And x86 doesn't have a double-indirect addressing-mode that could load from `bp-6` and then use that as the address to store to all in one instruction.  So even if that is how EMU8086 assembles it, the explanation doesn't make sense.  As Margaret said, could just be a bug.

Comment: I'm using FASM 1.73.30 on Linux.  Maybe EMU8086 uses an old modified version of FASM?  Using `localY equ bp-6`, I get an error when assembling `mov localY, ax` - it complains `processed: mov bp-6,ax` / `error: invalid operand.` as expected from the text substitution.  If EMU8086's FASM is totally different, then probably best to just say EMU8086, not FASM.

Comment: flat assembler version 1.64

Comment: I tried to compile in command line, using fasm 1.64 from emu8086's folder and I get error `mov bp-4, ax error: invalid operand.` It's obvious that it can't be done, move reg to immediate value.  I added screenshot just to see how emu8086 see things.

Comment: My bad, it seems that emu8086 got 2 compilation options `compile and load in the emulator` and `fasm`. First works ok as in attached screenshot, second generates same errors as in cmd-line.